# JSoup select Div based on Id and href based on title

Tags: java, parsing, jsoup

Im using JSoup to parse HTML response. I have multiple Div tags. I have to select Div tag based on an ID.

My pseudo code looks like this,

```
Document divTag = Jsoup.connect(link).get();
Elements info = divTag.select("div#navDiv");
```

where navDiv is the ID. But it doesnt seem to work.

Also I would want to select Href inside the Div based on some title, where hrefTitle[] would be string array. So while iterating the href I would check if the title is present in the string array, if so i would add them to list else ignore. How do i select href inside Div ? and How to select title? any inputs much appreciated.

Comment: Please post a sample of the HTML that you are trying to parse that is failing or not doing what you expect. It will make helping you debug this problem _much_ easier. Also, _actual_ code (rather than pseudo code) that you are having trouble with is helpful as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But it doesnt seem to work.

It *should* work. Proof:

```
Document doc = Jsoup.parse("<html><body><div/>" + 
    "<div id=\"navDiv\">" + 
        "<a href=\"href1\">link1</a>" +
        "<a href=\"href2\">link2</a><" +
    "</div></body></html>");
Element div = doc.select("div#navDiv").first();
```

Now, we can select the `a` element inside the `div` that has (for example) an `href` attribute whose value is `href2`:

```
System.out.println(div.select("a[href=href2]"));
```

Output:

```
<a href="href2">link2</a>
```

You can find the full selector syntax here:

- http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/select/Selector.html